# Use enumerate to reference sections

Tags: cross-referencing, enumerate

I am writing a user manual for a few coworkers, and while the nature of the document does not need a table of contents, it does have an introduction with an enumerated list of the following sections.

What I would like to do is `label` the sections so that my list can be references to where they appear in the text.

Right now, I have a simple `enumerate`, but when I change the `\item`s to `\ref`s (Ex1 below) I get a missing `\item` error.  If I keep the `\item` (Ex2), I get a numbered list where each item is a numbered reference as well.

Ex1:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{amsart}
\begin{document}

\section*{Introduction}
This is the introduction, here are the other sections in the manual.
\begin{enumerate}
\ref{sec:sa}
\ref{sec:sb}
\end{enumerate}

\section{Section A}\label{sec:sa}
\section{Section B}\label{sec:sb}

\end{document}
```

Ex2:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{amsart}
\begin{document}

\section*{Introduction}
This is the introduction, here are the other sections in the manual.
\begin{enumerate}
\item \ref{sec:sa}
\item \ref{sec:sb}
\end{enumerate}

\section{Section A}\label{sec:sa}
\section{Section B}\label{sec:sb}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to change this so that the enumeration is the reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `\ref` in the optional argument to `\item`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{amsart}
\begin{document}

\section*{Introduction}
This is the introduction, here are the other sections in the manual.
\begin{enumerate}
\item[\ref{sec:sa}] A
\item[\ref{sec:sb}] B
\end{enumerate}

\section{Section A}\label{sec:sa}
\section{Section B}\label{sec:sb}

\end{document}
```

[image]